# How to get Repeater's current ItemIndex in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

While `Container.ItemIndex` as a way to get current repeater's item index in data binding expression works perfectly fine `<%# Container.ItemIndex %>`, it does not work in pure code behind. `Container` is not declared or inaccessible.

How can I get repeater's current item index here:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <% If Container.ItemIndex = 2 Then %>
    TRUE/some longer HTML here/
    <% Else %>
    false/some longer HTML here/
    <% End If %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

EDIT

For cases with not much HTML code this will work, but I am looking for Code Render Block solution as per example above.

`<%#: If(Container.ItemIndex  = 2, "TRUE", "false") %>`

Comment: When you say "purely code behind" do you mean with nothing in the template? It's a slightly odd question to use a template then say 'without template-code'.

Comment: With Code Render Block, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "Code Render Blocks" in templated controls' templates. If you only care about whether your markup blocks will be rendered to HTML and it doesn't matter if it's evaluated, you could use the `Visible`/`visible` properties of controls.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div runat="server" visible=<%# Container.ItemIndex = 2 %>>
        TRUE/some longer HTML here/
    </div>
    <div runat="server" visible=<%# Container.ItemIndex <> 2 %>>
        false/some longer HTML here/
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, just drop in a button and pick up the repeter row.

So, say we have this repeater markup:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:290px;float:left;padding:10px">

            <div style="padding:5px;text-align:right">
                Hotel Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' />
                <br />
                First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                <br />
                Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'  />
                <br />
                City: <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("City") %>'  />
                <br />
                Province: <asp:TextBox ID="Province" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Province") %>'/>
                <br />
                Active: <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>
                <br />
            
                <asp:Button ID="cmdRowC" runat="server" Text="Row Click" OnClick="cmdRowC_Click"/>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div style="clear:both;height:5px"></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

and our code behind to fill this repeater:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Repeater1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        Repeater1.DataBind()
    End Using

End Sub
```

And we now have this:

[image]

So now the button code. Note how I just dropped in a standard button.

But, we now can't double click on the button to automatic wire up and create a event.

BUT YOU CAN do this to create a event:

In the button code markup, type in OnClick=

WHEN YOU HIT "=", then intel-sense will pop up a dialog for you to create a button click event like this:

[image]

So, now click on create new event. It "seems" like nothing occured, but if we flip to code behind you find the click event stub.

So, now in our click event code we can easy pick up the current repeater row, the values and yes even the index.

The code works like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdRowC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cBtn As Button = sender
    Dim rRow As RepeaterItem = cBtn.Parent

    Debug.Print("Row clicked = " & rRow.ItemIndex)

    Debug.Print("First Name = " & DirectCast(rRow.FindControl("txtFirst"), TextBox).Text)
    Debug.Print("Last Name = " & DirectCast(rRow.FindControl("txtLast"), TextBox).Text)
    Debug.Print("Hotel Name = " & DirectCast(rRow.FindControl("txtHotelName"), TextBox).Text)

End Sub
```

output:

```
Row clicked = 1
First Name = Darcy
Last Name = Caroll
Hotel Name = Athabasca Hotel
```

So, just drop in a plane jane button. When you click on it the event stub runs, and as you can see, we pick up the "Repeater row item".

From that row, we can get the row index, and of course pluck out any other control value from that row using find control.

eg:

```
Dim txtHotel as TextBox = rRow.FindControl("txtHotel")

debug.print ("Hotel name = " & txtHotel.Text)
```

So, once you have the repeater row, you don't need some container.ItemIndex expression, since the row item lets you get the given index row with:

```
rRow.ItemIndex
```

So, ItemIndex is available, and is avilable regardless if you have or include or use the conttin.ItemIndex in the markup.

There is VERY LITTLE need to mess around with that code in the markup.

Note how VERY clean and simple the above is. I suggest you MAKE HUGE efforts to avoid dumping vb code inside of the markup like you are doing. If you even want to convert to c#, or even just maintain that code? Put that code in the code behind area - not in the markup.

As above shows, for repeating data etc., you can use a Repeater, or even often I use a listview - as it allows a repeating layout to be created automatic for you, and without having to write looping code.

******************** EDIT ***************************

Ok, now that we have this working, say we wanted to put in a message in the repeater that

```
This hotel is Active
```

or

```
This hotel is NOT active!
```

Ok, so in our markup, we could drop in a label like this:

And now from the repeater property sheet, double click here to create the item data bound event:

[image]

It is now a simple matter to put in our code logic for each row like this:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound

    Dim rRow As RepeaterItem = e.Item

    Dim ckbox As CheckBox = rRow.FindControl("chkActive")

    Dim MyLabel As Label = rRow.FindControl("Label1")

    If ckbox.Checked Then
        MyLabel.Text = "This Hotel is Active!!!"
    Else
        MyLabel.Text = "Not active!"
    End If

End Sub
```

And output is now this:

[image]

So, once again, to conditional format the repeater, add color to active hotel, or whatever? Use the item bound event.

Say i wanted add to above that the HotelName is to be color blue when active, then we could do this:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound

    Dim rRow As RepeaterItem = e.Item

    Dim ckbox As CheckBox = rRow.FindControl("chkActive")

    Dim MyLabel As Label = rRow.FindControl("Label1")

    If ckbox.Checked Then
        MyLabel.Text = "This Hotel is Active!!!"
    Else
        MyLabel.Text = "Not active!"
    End If

    Dim txtHotel As TextBox = rRow.FindControl("txtHotelName")

    If ckbox.Checked Then
        txtHotel.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
    End If
End Sub
```

Again, nice easy clean code - no mess markup. We seperate the code logic from the markup.

Output now is this:

[image]

Again, note how we did not even write ANY looping code here!!!!

So you want to leverage the built in options for the repeater, and for a GridView, listView, and a repeater?

Use the row data bind event - it lets you format, even do math, or whatever you want for EACH row of the repeating controls. And as you can see, its plain jane easy to write code as a bonus.